# problema con SqlDataReader 3 capas Login asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas tardes quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando un logeo en 3 capas 
ya que estoy capturando mi valores en un SqlDataReader

**Este es mi CapaDatos.**

```
  public void LogeoUsuario(string cboAgencia, string clave, string usuario)
       {
           using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
               con2.Open();
               using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SP_TTareasLogeo", con2))
               {
                   cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                   cmd2.Parameters.Add("@oficina", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboAgencia;
                   cmd2.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = clave;
                   cmd2.Parameters.Add("@usernamecomprobante", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario;

                   cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();


               }
           }
       }
```

**Mi capa Negocio :**

```
 public void LogeoUsuario(string cboAgencia, string clave, string usuario)
       {
           D_Usuario Usuario = new D_Usuario();
           Usuario.LogeoUsuario(cboAgencia, clave, usuario);
       }
```

**Mi Capa Presentacion :**

```
 protected void btnLogeo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            N_Usuario Usuario = new N_Usuario();
            Usuario.LogeoUsuario(cboAgenciaUsuario.Text, txtClaveAgencia.Text, txtUsuario.Text);


            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                rd.Read();
                lblidperfil.Text = rd["perfil"].ToString();
                lbloficinass.Text = rd["oficina"].ToString();
                lblusuario.Text = rd["NombreCompleto"].ToString();
                lblidusuariologin.Text = rd["idusuario"].ToString();
                idoficinausuario.Text = rd["idoficina"].ToString();
                lblinfo.Text = "Autosizado.";
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblidperfil.Text, true);
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lbloficinass.Text, true);
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblusuario.Text, true);
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblidusuariologin.Text, true);
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(idoficinausuario.Text, true);
                Session["perfil"] = lblidperfil.Text;
                Session["oficina"] = lbloficinass.Text;
                Session["NombreCompleto"] = lblusuario.Text;
                Session["idusuario"] = lblidusuariologin.Text;
                Session["idoficina"] = idoficinausuario.Text;

                if (int.Parse(lblidperfil.Text) == 3)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("FrmAgenciaLima.aspx");
                }
                else if (int.Parse(lblidperfil.Text) == 4)
                {

                    if (rd.HasRows)
                    {
                        rd.Read();
                        lblidperfil.Text = rd["perfil"].ToString();
                        lbloficinass.Text = rd["oficina"].ToString();
                        lblusuario.Text = rd["NombreCompleto"].ToString();
                        lblidusuariologin.Text = rd["idusuario"].ToString();
                        idoficinausuario.Text = rd["idoficina"].ToString();
                        lblinfo.Text = "Autosizado.";
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblidperfil.Text, true);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lbloficinass.Text, true);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblusuario.Text, true);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblidusuariologin.Text, true);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(idoficinausuario.Text, true);
                        Session["perfil"] = lblidperfil.Text;
                        Session["oficina"] = lbloficinass.Text;
                        Session["NombreCompleto"] = lblusuario.Text;
                        Session["idusuario"] = lblidusuariologin.Text;
                        Session["idoficina"] = idoficinausuario.Text;

                    }

                    Response.Redirect("defaultSiguiente.aspx");
                }
                else if (int.Parse(lblidperfil.Text) == 1)
                {
                    if (rd.HasRows)
                    {
                        rd.Read();
                        lblidperfil.Text = rd["perfil"].ToString();
                        lbloficinass.Text = rd["oficina"].ToString();
                        lblusuario.Text = rd["NombreCompleto"].ToString();
                        lblidusuariologin.Text = rd["idusuario"].ToString();
                        idoficinausuario.Text = rd["idoficina"].ToString();
                        lblinfo.Text = "Autosizado.";
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblidperfil.Text, true);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lbloficinass.Text, true);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblusuario.Text, true);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblidusuariologin.Text, true);
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(idoficinausuario.Text, true);
                        Session["perfil"] = lblidperfil.Text;
                        Session["oficina"] = lbloficinass.Text;
                        Session["NombreCompleto"] = lblusuario.Text;
                        Session["idusuario"] = lblidusuariologin.Text;
                        Session["idoficina"] = idoficinausuario.Text;
                    }
                    Response.Redirect("defaulthost.aspx");
                }

                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
                }



            }
```

**Error :**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Y cuál sería el problema?** un método de `login` de tipo `void` es muy raro y no seria la forma correcta. además de solicitarle que **añada el código en texto y no en imágenes**

Comment: @Dev.Joel si claro disculpa ya lo edite mi pregunta si el problema es porque me sale ese error en SqlDataReader

Comment: @Pierro La instancia de SqlCommand es esta : SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SP_TTareasLogeo", con2))  , es así?

Comment: @Jorgesys si es asi en la capa datos amigo

Comment: @Jorgesys o es algo de malo esa instancia amigo

Comment: @Pierro el error es claro , **no tiene un objeto `cmd` en su capa de presentación**. Recordar que en la capa de presentación no habría necesidad de ejecutar `comandos`.

Comment: @Pierro ¿pudiste resolver este problema?

Comment: @Flxtr no amigo no lo pude resolver aun mi problema :(

Comment: Prepararé una respuesta :)

Comment: @Flxtr muchisimas Gracias amigo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varios detalles que se deben corregir, los enlistaré y posteriormente pondré los segmentos de código con los ajustes necesarios:

1. Al hacer la validación de un logueo de un usuario, éste te deberá regresar un resultado para saber si se realizó bien el inicio de sesión.
2. Los valores de retorno de la capa de Negocio y Datos se deben ajustar para regresar el tipo de dato deseado.
3. Una vez que se haya realizado el inicio de sesión, nuevamente tendrás que acceder a la capa de Negocio y a su vez a la capa de Datos para la asignación del perfil. Esta segunda llamada a base de datos la puedes ahorrar si con la primer consulta a base de datos asignas el perfil en caso que el usuario y contraseña sean correctos.
4. En la capa de presentación no requieres realizar *`if-else-if`* ya que siempre se están evaluando todas las condiciones declaradas, para este caso, es mejor utilizar un `switch()`.

Para este caso, nos apoyaremos de una clase, la cual tendrá las propiedades necesarias para poder asignar tanto los datos del usuario como los del perfil.

```
public class DatosUsuario
{
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string NombreUsuario { get; set; }
    public string NombreCompleto { get; set; }
    public string Perfil { get; set; }
    public int IdOficina { get; set; }
    public string Oficina { get; set; }
}
```

Capa de presentación:

```
protected void btnLogeo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    N_Usuario Usuario = new N_Usuario(); //<-- Instancia a la capa de Negocio
    DatosUsuario objUsuario = Usuario.LogeoUsuario(cboAgenciaUsuario.Text, txtClaveAgencia.Text, txtUsuario.Text);

    if (objUsuario.IdUsuario > 0)
    {
        rd.Read();
        lblidperfil.Text = objUsuario.Perfil;
        lbloficinass.Text = objUsuario.Oficina;
        lblusuario.Text = objUsuario.NombreCompleto;
        lblidusuariologin.Text = objUsuario.IdUsuario;
        idoficinausuario.Text = objUsuario.IdOficina;
        lblinfo.Text = "Autorizado."; // <--Antes decía Autosizado :P
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblidperfil.Text, true);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lbloficinass.Text, true);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblusuario.Text, true);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lblidusuariologin.Text, true);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(idoficinausuario.Text, true);
        Session["perfil"] = objUsuario.Perfil;
        Session["oficina"] = bjUsuario.Oficina;
        Session["NombreCompleto"] = objUsuario.NombreCompleto;
        Session["idusuario"] = objUsuario.IdUsuario;
        Session["idoficina"] = objUsuario.IdOficina;


        //Con el switch ya no necesitas evaluar todas las condicionne para saber a qué página requieres redireccionar
        int perfil = int.Parse(objUsuario.Perfil);

        switch (perfil)
        {
            case 1:
                Response.Redirect("defaulthost.aspx");
                break;
            case 3:
                Response.Redirect("FrmAgenciaLima.aspx");
                break;
            case 4:
                Response.Redirect("defaultSiguiente.aspx");
                break;
            default:
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
                break;
        }
    }
    else // <-- La validación de usuario y contraseña falló y requiere nuevamente ingresar las credenciales
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Capa de Negocio:

```
public DatosUsuario LogeoUsuario(string cboAgencia, string clave, string usuario)
{
    D_Usuario Usuario = new D_Usuario(); // <-- Instancia de la capa de datos
    return Usuario.LogeoUsuario(cboAgencia, clave, usuario);
}
```

Capa de datos:

```
public DatosUsuario LogeoUsuario(string cboAgencia, string clave, string usuario)
{
    DatosUsuario objUsuario = new DatosUsuario();

    using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con2.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SP_TTareasLogeo", con2))
        {
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@oficina", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboAgencia;
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = clave;
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@usernamecomprobante", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario;

            var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                objUsuario.IdUsuario = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("IdUsuario")) ? (int)0 : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("IdUsuario"));
                objUsuario.NombreUsuario = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NombreUsuario")) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("NombreUsuario"));
                objUsuario.NombreCompleto = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NombreCompleto")) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("NombreCompleto"));
                objUsuario.Perfil = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Perfil")) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Perfil"));
                objUsuario.IdOficina = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("IdOficina")) ? (int)0 : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("IdOficina"));
                objUsuario.Oficina = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Oficina")) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Oficina"));
            }

            return objUsuario;
        }
    }
}
```

Como verás, ahora el *Stored Procedure*  `SP_TTareasLogeo` también lo tendrás que modificar, es decir, de inicio validar que el usuario y la contraseña sean válidos, y si el resultado es positivo, debes regresar un `DataSet` con los nombres de campos `IdUsuario`, `NombreUsuario`, `NombreCompleto`, `Perfil`, `IdOficina` y `Oficina`.

*Nota: el código no está probado, es posible que salgan errores en su implementación.*

Answer (score 1):

Veo un problema conceptual: Si estás utilizando el diseño de 3-capas (datos, negocio, presentación) ¿por qué intentas utilizar un `SqlDataReader` en tu capa de presentación?

En todo caso, tu capa de datos debería encargarse de encargarse de leer el resultado y colocarlo en alguna estructura u objeto para ser utilizado por tu capa de negocio.  Luego, la capa de presentación obtiene los datos de la capa de negocio para presentarlos al usuario.

Answer (score 1):

@Pierro estas utilizando un objeto cmd que no lo envías como parámetro de salida entre las capas inferiores.

Además cmd no lo envías como resultado de las capas (y no deberías ) lo recomendado es que entre capas "burbujees" (aquí quiero decir lo que va pasando de capa en capa) objetos de negocios/dto (entidades). Es decir que en este caso particular en la capa de datos devuelvas un Usuario (con sus propiedades respectivas) 
Así la capa de datos solo es responsable de conocer "dónde ir a buscar y como recuperar esos datos". En este caso son comandos sobre una db SQL pero podría buscar en un webservice, api's, autenticar en alguna red social, etc. Por eso es la recomendación de no enviar como respuesta el cmd sino un objeto que recuperas o necesitas.

Incluso para pasar datos a capas inferiores también podrías pasar objetos y no grandes cantidades de parámetros (no porque no se pueda más que nada por el acoplamiento nuevamente) ... Imagínate enviar un modelo/objeto que tenga 3 propiedades

Sería en tu ejemplo que armes el Usuario y hagas return de dicho objeto o null. Así en la capa de negocio o incluso la presentación verifica si el objeto es null o ya tienes al usuario

También, y no menos importante el tema de password que comentas en el código que utilizas...  para que no sea un simple String te recomiendo utilizar SecureString un poco más seguro. Dale una mirada como ayuda este tipo de objeto para guardar la cadena de la contraseña

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score 0):

Para leer la instancia de `SqlCommand` dentro del método `btnLogeo_Click()`,  deberás definirla a nivel de clase :

```
 SqlCommand cmd ;
```

obtener el valor:

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_TTareasLogeo", con2);
```

y de esta forma podrás utilizarla dentro del método:

```
protected void btnLogeo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            N_Usuario Usuario = new N_Usuario();
            Usuario.LogeoUsuario(cboAgenciaUsuario.Text, txtClaveAgencia.Text, txtUsuario.Text);


            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
...
...
```

Es importante comentarte que si estas estructurando tu proyecto en capas, en tu capa de presentación no deberías ejecutar comandos.